# Is Archaeologist badge still given to SO users?

Tags: bug, badges

In my profile on Stack Overflow, I don't see the *Archaeologist* badge in  the *Available* tab when selecting my next badge. When I clicked on *Silver* tab, I still don't see it. But when I visited the [*Badges* page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), I see it is present.

I was previously informed that if a badge can be given multiple times, then it will not be present in *Available*, but I don't think *Archaeologist* badge is given multiple times?

Am I missing something or it is a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was a bug earlier. Today, when I looked into the list again it shows Archaeologist badge. See following pic (edited image a bit, removed actual count). :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the badge is [still available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist) and actively being earned by users.

Not all badges are listed when selecting a new badge to aim for; in this case the developers probably did not want people to go and seek out old posts *just* to earn the *Excavator* and *Archaeologist* badges.

Comment: I've already earned `Excavator badge`. You can check my profile. But still I don't see it. So, is it a bug? :|

Comment: @Abhishek: ah, no, Excavator is not listed either. Then it's just not listed to because it might encourage people to earn it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @martijin oh..k, it makes sense. But it is not logical. I mean, if users wants to earn badge, then he/she can look into badges link and still try to get it :)